# Proof of the cancellation law for natural numbers without the axiom of the succesor

Tags: induction, natural-numbers

We are to show $\forall m,n,p\in \mathbb{N_{0}}:m+p=n+p\implies m=n$.

*Proof*. Let $m,n\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$.

**Base case:** If $p=0$, then $m+p=m$ and $n+p=n$ which clearly establishes $p=0\implies (m+p=n+p\implies m=n)$

**Induction step:** For a fixed $q\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ we are to prove that \begin{align*}(m+q=n+q\implies m=n)\implies \Big(m+(q+1)=n+(q+1)\implies m=n\Big)\tag{$i$}\end{align*} We proceed by way of contradiction and to that end we suppose there exist $q\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ such that $\sim (i)$. Since we know $q$ exists we may let $q=1$ so from $(i)$ we know \begin{align*}m+1=n+1\implies m=n\tag{$ii$}\end{align*} and \begin{align*}(m+1)+1=(n+1)+1\tag{$iii$}\end{align*} Since $m$ and $n$ in $(ii)$ can by any numbers and because $(m+1)$ and $(n+1)$ are numbers themselves, from $(iii)$ by applying $(ii)$ we know $m+1=n+1$ and, again, by $(ii)$ we've showed $m=n$ which contradicts our assumption $\sim (i)$.

**Is it wrong this attempt of proof? If it is, may you help me by providing a proof by contradiction of this basic statement?**

Comment: You need to use that there is an injective successor function on the natural numbers somewhere in your proof. If you didn't have that axiom, the claim would be false.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht That is incorrect. You can axiomatize $\mathbb{N}$without mentioning the injectivity of the successor function.

Comment: @MichaelBarz Thanks for pointing that out. I was assuming that the OP uses the Peano axioms, since they did not specify otherwise and that is the standard. If they want to use another axiomatic system, they should state so.

Comment: Can you assume $+$ associates?

Comment: @J.G actually yes

Comment: So if $(m+q)+1=(n+q)+1$, there are two steps left.

Comment: @J.G What do you mean? The proof is wrong, isnt't? I try to understand, sorry :(

Comment: I was suggesting another way to complete the inductive step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition of natural numbers have been defined recursively as-
$$a+0=a$$
$$a+S(b)=S(a+b)$$
where $S$ is the successor function.

So, without assuming axiom of successor, you cannot even define addition on $\mathbb N$. So, there's no question of a cancellation law.

Comment: You do not know which axiomatization of $\mathbb{N}$ the user has. There are ways to avoid the successor function in axiomatizations, for instance by taking addition itself to be a primitive concept, instead of addition by 1. Then it is perfectly valid to ask how to prove via induction that addition has this injectivity.

Comment: @MichaelBarz Thanks, I didn't know that construction. Any links to read that (the one without using successor function) please?

Comment: One can define $\mathbb{Z}$ as the initial object in the category of rings, and then define the natural numbers as the set of positive numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SayanDutta Is it possible to prove the statement without using the axiom of succesor in the proof?

Comment: @HannyBoy The way I (and *I think* you as well) sudied $\mathbb N$, i.e., using Peano's axioms, I think sum cannot be even defined without using the successor function. But, as Michael points out, if there is a way to define $\mathbb N$ using addition itself to be a primitive concept, then it may happen that we somehow avoid the concept of a successor in the definition. But, I don't know category of rings, so I can't tell anything more than this. Maybe Michael can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume $q=1.$ $q$ is a generic natural number.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this without using the axiom of succesor?

Comment: @HannyBoy What is your axomization of $\mathbb{N}$? The proof of this fact depends entirely upon that.

Comment: Despite having assumed that $q$ exists (which I thought enabled me to chose a value for it) May you explain me, please, why It's not possible to let $q=1$ :( I try to understand.

Comment: @HannyBoy Here is how induction works: You try to prove that if a statement holds for $q,$ it holds for $q+1,$ regardless of $q.$

Comment: I reckon the axomization of $\mathbb{N_{0}}$ which appers later on my class textbook the axiom of succesor is mentioned. Despite that being the axomination of $\mathbb{N}$ I am to use. Isn't it possible to prove it without such an axiom?

Comment: Your proof, if it was valid, would only prove that if $m+1 = n+1$ implies $m=n,$ then $m+2 = n+2$ implies $m=n.$ (Although, your proof is still unsatisfactory.) This is not sufficient to prove cancellation in general.

Comment: @HannyBoy What are you axioms for the natural numbers? List all of them